# I changed the default locations of erlang and rabbitmq and things are not working

Tags: linux, rabbitmq, centos, erlang

I am working on a remote server with CentOS 7 as its OS and my job is to install and run RabbitMQ on it. Due to some work-related reasons, I am only allowed to install packages on the `/home/sysadmin/service` folder, and hence I use the `mv` command to move erlang and rabbitmq from their initial locations (`/usr/lib64/erlang` and `/usr/lib/rabbitmq`, respectively) to `/home/sysadmin/service`. After doing that, I encourtered these errors:

- When I run `./erl`, I got: `./erl: line 34: /usr/lib64/erlang/erts-12.3.2.1/bin/erlexec: No such file or directory`
- When I run `sudo ./rabbitmqctl status` or any other rabbitmqctl command, I got: `unable to perform an operation on node 'rabbit@USERNAME'`

I have tried adding the new location of the bin folders of both erl and rabbitmq to PATH but things still didn't work. I have also tried looking for answers on Google but nothing seems to resolve my issues.
Can anyone provide me with a solution and an explanation for why this happens?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't move Erlang this way. You would have to compile it yourself and specify the installation directory as arguments to `configure`:

```
./configure --prefix=/home/sysadmin/service/erlang
```

Whatever your reasons are, the headaches aren't worth doing this.